# Sgplot for multiple response variables

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with over 50,000 records that looks like the following; ID, season(either high or low), bed_time and triage_time in minutes:

```
 ID Season Bed_time Triage_time 
 1  high    34            68
 2  low     44            20
 3  high    90            14
 4  low     71            88
 5  low     27            54
```

I would like to create a GROUPED VERTICAL BAR CHART where both then Bed_time Triage_time are reflected as a median and grouped by season on the X-axis:

```
 |   |                       |
 |   |                   |   |
 |   |    |              |   |
 |-------------------------------
     BT  TT              BT  TT
      High                 Low
```

I reckon I have to transpose the data and then plug into an SGPLOT, but I'm not quite sure how to do that to ensure that data can then be graphed.

```
 proc sgplot data=mysas.projects;
 vbar season/ stat=median 
 group=[Bed_time Triage_time] /*NEED FROM TRANSPOSED DATA*/
 groupdisplay=cluster;
 run;
 quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you will need to reshape data from wide to long to use `group` call. Additionally, you will need to include a `response` call. Consider `proc transpose` for reshaping:

```
*** POSTED DATA
data time_data;
   length Season $ 5;
   input ID Season $ Bed_time Triage_time;   
   cards;
 1  high    34            68
 2  low     44            20
 3  high    90            14
 4  low     71            88
 5  low     27            54
;
run;

*** RESHAPE LONG TO WIDE;
proc transpose 
    data = time_data
    out = time_data_long
    name = time_group;
    by ID Season;
run;

*** CLEAN UP OUTPUT;
data time_data_long;
    set time_data_long;

    label time_group = "Time Group";
    rename col1 = value;
run;

proc sgplot data=time_data_long;
    vbar season / response=value stat=median 
    group = time_group
    groupdisplay=cluster;
run;
```

[image: Plot Output]